# How to resolve Go module declares its path as "x" but was required as "y" between 2 versions

Tags: go, go-modules

I recently had to move private repositories from SaaS Gitlab to an on-premise version. Everything was going well where I did:

1. Update old go module paths in repo `a` from `old.com/workspace/a` to `new.com/workspace/a`
2. Add a new tag `v1.2.3-new` to the latest commit
3. Update repo `b` to reference latest tag `v1.2.3-new` from `new.com/workspace/a`
4. Run `go mod tidy` in repo `b` and verify it works

Now I have a requirement to reference an older version tag of `new.com/workspace/a` (originally `old.com/workspace/a`). So in repo `a`, I checked out the older tag, fixed up the module path to `new.com/workspace/a` from `old.com/workspace/a` and tagged it as `v1.1.1-new`.

In repo `b` then I referenced `new.com/workspace/a` with `v1.1.1-new`. However, this results in:

```
go: new.com/workspace/a@v1.1.1-new: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: old.com/workspace/b
            but was required as: new.com/workspace/b
```

If I check the `v1.1.1-new` tag in repo `a`, the module path is set correctly in the `go.mod`file:

```
module new.com/workspace/a
```

It is unclear to me why it works with the tag `v1.2.3-new` on the latest commit but fails when I reference an older commit.

Comment: The `go.mod` in `v1.1.1-new` likely still lists the old repo.

Comment: This is what the message is saying so I've triple checked it. I've just tested with the commit for  tag `v1.1.1-new` and to my surprise it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't say I fully understood why this worked but here are the steps that made it work (including what didn't).

1. I resorted to clearing the cache with `go clean -modcache`
2. Tested with the following but it still failed.

   ```
   go get new.com/workspace/a@v1.1.1-new
   ```
3. As per my comment in the original question, this worked via the `v1.1.1-new` commit hash So I resorted to that again.

   ```
   go get  new.com/workspace/a@27ca81f7
   ```

   Now it picked up the version for that commit and was successful. The
   `go.mod` file was also correctly updated with the tag/version despite
   using the commit hash in the `go get` command.

   ```
   new.com/workspace/a v1.1.1-new
   ```